# How to find source of custom class in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have this particular code snippet in a JS file:

```
var fileView = Ext.create('My.ext.File.Panel', {
            style: 'border:none;',
            loadMask: {
                msg: 'Please wait ...'
        ...
```

And when i search i can see that `My.ext.File.Panel` appears in the `requires` config of various custom components.

But i am not able to find `Ext.define('My.ext.File.Panel'` anywhere in the source.

Can anybody shed some light or point me to how i can find out the source for this custom panel - `My.ext.File.Panel`. I have tried debugging with dev-tools in chrome and firefox but could not get it, not sure where to look.

Thank You

Comment: You are searching this code in dev console or editor ?

Comment: @Tejas Tried both.

Comment: Also i was just thinking are there other ways to `define` a class without using `Ext.define`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to create a class in ExtJs or to assign an alias. Perhaps the class name is assembled using variables.

The `Ext.ClassManager` has a debug function, which can record any registration of a class. Insert the code example below before you start your application. This should help you to get to the code that defines the class.

```
Ext.classSystemMonitor = function(className){
  if(className === 'My.ext.File.Panel')
  {
      console.log(className, arguments);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try and update. `Perhaps the class name is assembled using variables.` hmmm ... that might be the case.

Comment: I am not sure how can i use this. Can you please help?

Comment: I use the following:  
1) in addition to console.log I add a `debugger;` statement  
2) insert the codeblock into my `app.js` file before the application is defined with` Ext.application`.  
3) If the debugger (Chrome Dev Tools should be open) stops in place, I look in the call stack from where the calls came.   

There you should find a file which is not in the ExtJs core.Here an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21fl